# Fatal error: Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: soap, fatal-error

I use this code for send and get item price from WebService:

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$username = 'myusername';
$password = 'mypassword';
$kol = '3000';
$weight = '200';
$state = '51';
$city = '8';
$type = '0';

$option = array('login' => $username , 'password' => $password);
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.wbservice.info/Webservice/wsdl.php',$option);
$soap = $client->getProxy(); 
$response = $soap -> GetSendPrice($kol , $weight , $state , $city , $type);
      echo $response;
```

But thats returne me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function GetSendPrice() on a non-object in /sample.php on line 20
```

I try this code :

```
$response = $soap ->call( 'GetSendPrice',array(30000 , 200 , 51 , 8 , 0));
```

return me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function call() on a non-object in /sample.php on line 21
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem is in the Webservice you are calling and not in the code you are using to call it.